# Responsive design object change places

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Sometimes when viewing responsive sites I see two div's which appear next to each other in full screen but one on top of the other when the screen size is smaller.

This is a simple use of max-width=% , width=px and float

However
Sometimes the one which is on the RIGHT in full screen mode appears on TOP when they stack on top of each other on a smaller display.

The first behavior requires the one on the right to be the first one in the DOM
but the second behavior requires it to be the second one in the DOM
and the HTML file is the same for all screen resolutions.

So how is this effect achieved?

Comment: "the second behavior requires it to be the second one in the DOM" -- [No it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz57L/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found your question little bit confusing but this is what I've understood :

- You want to achieve responsive web design
- You want sidebar to be on right on desktop width
- When you open the website on mobile / small screen, sidebar or the content from right should go on top instead of bottom.

If I am correct then this is the way to do it..

1. Place right side content above left side content and add property `float:right` to it..
2. Place the left container below it..
3. Apply media queries..

Demo using Bootstrap : http://jsfiddle.net/YEUwN/95/

Answer (score 0):

For three divs, you could use this css trick.

```
#example {display: table; width: 100%; }
#block-1 {display: table-footer-group; } 
#block-2 {display: table-row-group;    }
#block-3 {display: table-header-group; } 

<div id="example">
    <div id="block-1">First</div>
    <div id="block-2">Second</div>
    <div id="block-3">Third</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47T89/

That's going to display
third
second
first

And if you want more, you gonna have to wait it's actually a W3C working draft
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/